# Hadoop: Measuring the duration of each phase(map, shuffle/sort, reduce)

Tags: java, hadoop

There's a very similar question what I want to know.
[How can I measure the duration of each phase(map, shuffle/sort, reduce) in Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188887/how-can-i-measure-the-duration-of-each-phasemap-shuffle-sort-reduce-in-hadoo)
The answer says that web/ui of tasktracker shows each duration of the application. But my environment is hadoop-2.2.0 and there's no tasktracker. So tasktracker web/ui *"localhost:50030/tasktracker.jsp"* is not working. The answer is appropriate only for lower version of hadoop(1.x.x), I guess.

How can I measure the duration of each phase(map, shuffle/sort, reduce) in hadoop-2.x.x version? Is there any other web/ui for check them?

My environment: Red hat 6.3, hadoop-2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information can be seen via `jobhistory` URL `http://localhost:19888/jobhistory`.Click on "job id" from the "retired job" list and it will show you average map,reduce,shuffle and merge time for job. If you click on map or reduce tasks you can see details about each task's start and end time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I run and terminate some applications but there's no Retired Jobs in the table. I mean, there's a Retired Jobs table but no entry showing up. Just an empty table. Do I have to configure something before running application?